# iOS InputAccessory view wrong orientation

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone, inputaccessoryview

I have a view which can be rotated while whole other application is not.
The rotation being done using view transform rather than rotation whole viewController.
The issue is that in a landscape mode keyboard's inputaccessory view has wrong orientation - keyboard is being shown correctly in landscape mode, while inputAccessory view is being shown as in portrait:

[image]

In portrait orientation all looks correctly:

[image]

I'm using extension to build input accessory view:

```
extension UITextField
{
    static var _doneAccessoryViewButtonCallback = [String:()->Void]()
    
    var doneAccessoryViewButtonCallback:(()->Void)? {
        get {
            let tmpAddress = String(format: "%p", unsafeBitCast(self, to: Int.self))
            return UITextField._doneAccessoryViewButtonCallback[tmpAddress]
        }
        set(newValue) {
            let tmpAddress = String(format: "%p", unsafeBitCast(self, to: Int.self))
            UITextField._doneAccessoryViewButtonCallback[tmpAddress] = newValue
        }
    }
    
    @IBInspectable var doneAccessory: Bool{
        get{
            return self.doneAccessory
        }
        set (hasDone) {
            if hasDone{
                addDoneButtonOnKeyboard()
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    func addDoneButtonOnKeyboard()
    {
        let view:UIView = UIView()
        view.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(0), width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: CGFloat(44))
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.RGB(hexString: "#D1D5DB")
        
        let button: UIButton = self.getButton()
        
        view.addSubview(button)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.constrainToRightOfSuperView(CGFloat(16))
        button.centerVerticallyInSuperView()
        
        
        self.inputAccessoryView = view
        
        let version = OperatingSystemVersion(majorVersion: 13, minorVersion: 0, patchVersion: 0)
        if ProcessInfo.processInfo.isOperatingSystemAtLeast(version) {
            view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.stretchToBoundsOfSuperView()
        } else {
            view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
        }
    }
    
    func isEmpty() -> Bool
    {
        return self.text == nil || self.text!.count == 0
    }
    
    // MARK: -
    // MARK: - PRIVATES
    private func getButton() -> UIButton
    {
        let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
        
        let attString:NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Done")
        attString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.RGB(0xed, g: 0x3c, b: 00), range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attString.string.length))
        attString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.font, value: UIFont(name: "Avenir-Book", size: 17)!, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attString.string.length))
        button.setAttributedTitle(attString, for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(doneButtonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        return button
    }
    
    @objc func doneButtonAction()
    {
        self.resignFirstResponder()
        self.doneAccessoryViewButtonCallback?()
    }
}
```

Comment: What was the solution for this issue?

Comment: I'm not sure regarding the solution since we did a lot of refactoring, but I think it was related to some window that was on top and it was not the window in which I was showing the keyboard and it was portrait.